# sql query to fetch tag information from single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (Mysql) with different snippets with tags in a coloumns

```
table snippets
---------------
Id title source tag
1 "title"  "srouce code"  "Zend, Smarty"
2 "title2"  "srouce code2"  "Zend jquery"
3 "title3"  "srouce code3"  "doctrine"
```

I want to do a select statements so that I can build a tag clouds on my site.

```
Zend(2), smarty(1), jquery(1), doctrine(1)
```

Remember tages are not always sperated by space, some tages are separated by comma(,)

then I need a query to fetch all records with specific tages. which I think i can use something like that untill there is better solution for that.

```
Select * from snippets where tag like "%ZEND%"
```

looking for optimized solutions please.

Comment: do any one comments when marking negative .... whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create three tables!

```
table snippets
id | title    | source_code
1    "title"    "srouce code" 
2    "title2"   "srouce code2" 
3    "title3"   "srouce code3" 

table tags
id | tag
1    "zend"
2    "smarty"
3    "doctrine"
4    "jquery"

table snippets_tags 
id | snippet_id | tag_id
1        1          1
2        1          2
3        2          1
4        2          4
5        3          3
```

**Tip:** lower-case your tags because "Zend" and "zend" are the same

Now your tag cloud query should look like

```
SELECT tags.name, COUNT(snippets_tags.id) AS snippet_count 
   FROM tags LEFT JOIN snippets_tags ON snippets_tags.tag_id = tags.id 
      GROUP BY tags.id
```

Gives you a result like

```
name  | snippet_count
zend         2
smarty       1
doctrine     1
jquery       1
```

To select all snippets belonging to a certain tag:

```
SELECT snippets.*  FROM snippets, tags, snippets_tags 
  WHERE 
    snippets_tags.snippets_id = snippet.id AND 
    snippets_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND 
    tags.name LIKE '%zend%'
```

Comment: that is well normalized. Is there a way in sql that i can go with existing table structure because every thing is already done badly. Don't want to spent much time to change the whole structure. Is there any sql query which can do the work with existing structure. Thanks for your help sled. I really appriciate.

Comment: You could use regular expressions if performance doesn't matter: 
`SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name REGEXP "(^|[, ]+)zend($|[, ]+)"` gets you only "zend" tags something like "zendalicous" would not match! But "blabla,zend,something" or "blabla zend, blabla" would match. [Read more about Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about separating the source code and tags into separate tables?

```
Source Table
ID, Title, Source
1   "t1"   "sc"
2   "t2"   "sc"
3   "t3"   "sc"

Tag Table
ID, Tag
1   "Zend"
2   "Smarty"
3   "jquery"
4   "doctrine"

SourceTagLink Table
SourceID, TagID
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         3
3         4
```

That way you have a unique list of tags that you can choose from, or add to.
You wont be doing any string parsing so your selects will be much faster. Sort of similar to how you assign tags to your post on this site.

**EDIT**
This is a function that I used to convert a multivalue string into a table with a single column it written is MSSQL but you should be able to convert it to mySQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseString](@String NVARCHAR(4000), @Delimiter CHAR(1)=',')
           RETURNS @Result TABLE(tokens NVARCHAR(4000))
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- We will be seearching for the index of each occurrence of the given
        -- delimiter in the string provided, and will be extracting the characters
        -- between them as tokens.
        DECLARE @delimiterIndex INT
        DECLARE @token NVARCHAR(4000)

        -- Try to find the first delimiter, and continue until no more can be found.
        SET @delimiterIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)
        WHILE (@delimiterIndex > 0)
        BEGIN
            -- We have found a delimiter, so extract the text to the left of it
            -- as a token, and insert it into the resulting table.
            SET @token = LEFT(@String, @delimiterIndex-1)
            INSERT INTO @Result(tokens) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@token)))

            -- Chop the extracted token and this delimiter from our search string,
            -- and look for the next delimiter.
            SET @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String)-@delimiterIndex)
            SET @delimiterIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)
        END
        -- We have no more delimiters, so place the remainder of the string
        -- into the result as our last token.
        SET @token = @String
        INSERT INTO @Result(tokens) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@token)))
        RETURN
    END
```

Basically you call it like

```
ParseString('this be a test', ' ')
it will return a single column table

this    
be
a
test

ParseString('this:be a test', ':')
returns

this
be a test
```

You could add a call to the function in an update trigger to populate the new tables to help you make selects much easier. Once the trigger is built, just do a simple update like the following

```
Update yourTable
Set Title = Title
```

That fill fire the trigger and populate the new tables and make everything much easier for you without affecting existing code. Of course youll need to replace all known delimeters with a single one for it to work.
Any new records added or modified will automatically fire the trigger.

Comment: this probably is the best way to normalize the table. But I don't want to change the structure of the table as it could unstable other modules. Is this the only way to do that? or I can work around with some sql query.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to replace all characters like ',' space etc. with a fixed "separator" character like '#'. You could use a temporary table.

Then you have to create a function that loops over the fields and searches and counts the single tags.

Comment: is there any sql solution? I know it is not the best way to store in a single table. but that is what it has been done by predessors. So I have to deal with that.